# Is there a way to use Plotly as an annotation tool, for labelling time-series for instance?

Tags: python, time-series, visualization, supervised-learning, labels

I have been tasked to create a tool aimed at labelling sections and/or precise data points of a biomedical time-series. Our main framework is written in Python.

I would like to know whether it is possible to do it with Plotly, and if so, would someone mind sharing their experience?

Kind regards,
Bertrand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are helpful annotation tools (if any)](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28594/what-are-helpful-annotation-tools-if-any)

Comment: Thanks for the link @SvanBalen but unfortunately, it is mainly for text annotations, not for time-series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use Plotly as an annotation tool for labelling time-series or other data. Plotly provides a range of annotation options, including text annotations, shapes, and arrows, which can be used to label specific points or regions in a plot.

**Plotly Annotation Features:**

1. The Annotations feature, allows you to add text labels or notes to specific points on the plot.
2. The Annotations Editor, provides a user-friendly interface for adding and editing annotations on the plot.
3. The add_annotations() function, which allows you to programmatically add annotations to the plot using Python or R code.

To use Plotly as an annotation tool, you can first create a time-series plot using the `plotly.express` or `plotly.graph_objects` functions. Then, you can use the `add_annotation()` method to add annotations to the plot. This method allows you to specify the x and y coordinates of the annotation and the `text`, `color`, `font size`, and other attributes of the annotation.

For example, to add a text annotation to a time-series plot, you could use the following code:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder()

fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", color="continent")

fig.add_annotation(x=1970, y=70, text="Annotation text",
                   font=dict(size=16), arrowcolor="red")

fig.show()
```

This code would create a line plot of life expectancy over time, and add a text annotation at the `point (1970, 70)` with the text **"Annotation text"** and a **red arrow pointing to that point**.

or you can use the `annotations` attribute of the `layout` object in **Plotly**. This attribute is a list of annotations, where each annotation is a dictionary containing the information for a single annotation, such as the text to display and the position of the annotation. Here is an example of how you can use the annotations attribute to label the time-series data in a
**Plotly chart:**

```
import plotly.express as px

# Generate some dummy time-series data
df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent == 'Oceania'")

# Create a line chart of the time-series data
fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="gdpPercap", color="country")

# Add annotations to the chart
fig.update_layout(
    annotations=[
        dict(
            x=1955,
            y=10000,
            text="Annotation 1",
            showarrow=True,
            arrowhead=7,
            ax=0,
            ay=-40
        ),
        dict(
            x=1975,
            y=20000,
            text="Annotation 2",
            showarrow=True,
            arrowhead=7,
            ax=0,
            ay=-40
        ),
    ]
)

fig.show()
```

More examples from official **Plotly** documentation : [Text and annotations in Python - Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/)

Overall, Plotly provides a range of tools and options for annotating time-series or other data, allowing you to easily label specific points or regions in your plots.